# How to deploy spring boot application without changing records on database on kubernetes?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, kubernetes, docker-compose, kompose

I have a **Spring Boot** application which acts as REST API it uses **JPA** and **Hibernate** to map object to **PostgreSQL** database tables. I am looking to deploy my application on release over Kubernetes. The whole application is built using the tool **docker-compose** then converted using the tool **Kompose**. Some times object model is changed so database table schema for that object. What is the best practice to deploy my application and new database schemas to **Kubernetes** without changing records or losing users data or avoiding any database conflict?

Comment: Use some sort of database migration management tool, eg liquibase

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/to-run-or-not-to-run-a-database-on-kubernetes-what-to-consider

Answer (score 1):

You should disable hibernate schema creation to ensure it does not delete data.

Next you should investigate if Liquibase https://www.liquibase.org/ or Flyway https://flywaydb.org/ suits your use case to bundle migrations as part of your application.

Comment: So for liquibase I tested it did a small project which connects to postgresql database, I did a modification on one of the columns as an example of scenario deleted column **first** with **first_name** then did sync liquibase data but it does not apply the updates. I do see the column **first_name** but it has null value. So liquibase does not backup data and it can't transfer data from old column to new column?

Comment: That is correct, you need to create a custom migration that honors your intention by either copying the data or - even better - renaming the column instead of creating a new one

Comment: @I tried liquibase but when code is pushed I have a **gitlab-runner** which builds a new docker image and push it to container registry after that it converts docker image with **Kompose** to **Kubernetes** artifact but the docker container for database will be dropped within the pod, so how to go around this?